# Access Database Append Query Invalid Procedure Call

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to run an append query which was running fine until now (I run the query every month). I receive an "Invalid Procedure Call" error now even though nothing has changed. The underlying `select` query runs OK.

Below is the code for the `append` query -

```sql
INSERT INTO 
    Audit_Vsurvey_All_Data_t 
    ( 
        Department, 
        LAST_NAME, 
        FIRST_NAME, 
        [Last Name], 
        [First Name], 
        [CPM ID], 
        [HP Author], 
        Provider, 
        [Chart ID], 
        Audit_Date, 
        Admit_Date, 
        [Question Group], 
        HP_Contains_Allergies, 
        HP_Contains_Assessment, 
        HP_Contains_Chief_Complaint, 
        HP_Vitals, 
        HP_Contains_Family_History, 
        HP_Contains_HX_Present_Illness, 
        HP_Contains_Diagnostic_Tests, 
        HP_Contains_Medications, 
        HP_Contains_Medical_History, 
        HP_Contains_Surgical_History, 
        HP_Contains_Review_Of_Systems, 
        HP_Contains_Social_History, 
        HP_Contains_Treatment_Plan, 
        HP_Documented_In_30_Days, 
        Charted_Within_24
    ) 
SELECT 
    [TT2870-LA Active].Department_Name & " " & [TT2870-LA Active].SECTION_NAME AS Department, 
    [TT2870-LA Active].LAST_NAME, 
    [TT2870-LA Active].FIRST_NAME, 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[Last Name],
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[First Name],
    [TT2870-LA Active].[CPM ID], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].Author, 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].Provider, 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[Chart ID], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].Audit_Date, 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].Admit_Date, 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[Question Group], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[H&P contains allergies], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[H&P contains assessment/impression], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[H&P contains chief complaint], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[H&P contains current physical examination], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[H&P contains family history], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[H&P contains history of present illness], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit]. [H&P contains labs/diagnostic test results], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[H&P contains medications], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[H&P contains past medical history], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[H&P contains past surgical history], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[H&P contains review of systems], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[H&P contains social history], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[H&P contains the treatment plan], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[H&P is was documented less than 30 days from admission date_], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[H&P present within 24 hours of admission] 
FROM 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit] LEFT JOIN [TT2870-LA Active] ON 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[Last Name] = [TT2870-LA Active].LAST_NAME AND 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].LastSplit = [TT2870-LA Active].FIRST_NAME 
WHERE
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].Audit_Date Between #10/1/2018# And #12/31/2018#
```

Is there a way to tell what is causing the error looking at the above code since I can't post the data.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Possible extra space after dot   [vsurvey data to namesplit]. [h&p contains labs/diagnostic test results],

Answer (score 0):

Formatting your SQL code with appropriate indentation reveals a couple of oddities which I've annotated in the code below:

```sql
INSERT INTO 
    Audit_Vsurvey_All_Data_t 
    ( 
        Department, 
        LAST_NAME, 
        FIRST_NAME, 
        [Last Name], 
        [First Name], 
        [CPM ID], 
        [HP Author], 
        Provider, 
        [Chart ID], 
        Audit_Date, 
        Admit_Date, 
        [Question Group], 
        HP_Contains_Allergies, 
        HP_Contains_Assessment, 
        HP_Contains_Chief_Complaint, 
        HP_Vitals, 
        HP_Contains_Family_History, 
        HP_Contains_HX_Present_Illness, 
        HP_Contains_Diagnostic_Tests, 
        HP_Contains_Medications, 
        HP_Contains_Medical_History, 
        HP_Contains_Surgical_History, 
        HP_Contains_Review_Of_Systems, 
        HP_Contains_Social_History, 
        HP_Contains_Treatment_Plan, 
        HP_Documented_In_30_Days, 
        Charted_Within_24
    ) 
SELECT 
    [TT2870-LA Active].Department_Name & " " & [TT2870-LA Active].SECTION_NAME AS Department, 
    [TT2870-LA Active].LAST_NAME, 
    [TT2870-LA Active].FIRST_NAME, 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[Last Name],
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[First Name],
    [TT2870-LA Active].[CPM ID], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].Author, 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].Provider, 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[Chart ID], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].Audit_Date, 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].Admit_Date, 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[Question Group], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[H&P contains allergies], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[H&P contains assessment/impression], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[H&P contains chief complaint], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[H&P contains current physical examination], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[H&P contains family history], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[H&P contains history of present illness], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit]. [H&P contains labs/diagnostic test results], 
                                ^------- Extra space here
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[H&P contains medications], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[H&P contains past medical history], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[H&P contains past surgical history], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[H&P contains review of systems], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[H&P contains social history], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[H&P contains the treatment plan], 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[H&P is was documented less than 30 days from admission date_], 
                                                                Should this be here? -------^
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[H&P present within 24 hours of admission] 
FROM 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit] LEFT JOIN [TT2870-LA Active] ON 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[Last Name] = [TT2870-LA Active].LAST_NAME AND 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].LastSplit = [TT2870-LA Active].FIRST_NAME 
WHERE
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].Audit_Date Between #10/1/2018# And #12/31/2018#
```

If the above suggestions do not address the issue, I could only really suggest that, for each of the fields being appended, you temporarily replace the expression in the `select` statement with a default value for that field, repeating for all fields until the query evaluates without error.

For example, to test whether the first field is causing the problem, temporarily change the appended value to a default string value constituting valid data for the field, e.g.:

```sql
INSERT INTO 
    Audit_Vsurvey_All_Data_t 
    ( 
        Department, 
        LAST_NAME, 
        FIRST_NAME, 
        -- ... < more fields > ...
        Charted_Within_24
    ) 
SELECT 
    "Default Department" AS Department, -- Temporarily change to a default value
    [TT2870-LA Active].LAST_NAME, 
    [TT2870-LA Active].FIRST_NAME, 
    -- ... < more fields > ...
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[H&P present within 24 hours of admission] 
FROM 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit] LEFT JOIN [TT2870-LA Active] ON 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].[Last Name] = [TT2870-LA Active].LAST_NAME AND 
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].LastSplit = [TT2870-LA Active].FIRST_NAME 
WHERE
    [Vsurvey data to NameSplit].Audit_Date Between #10/1/2018# And #12/31/2018#
```

That will enable you to ascertain which of the fields is causing the error so that you may investigate further.

Comment: Thanks but the extra space was a type when trying to paste the code here. Yes and the field - [H&P is was documented less than 30 days from admission date_] is valid. Still get the invalid procedure call error.

Comment: @JHegde Aside from the noted points, your SQL looks valid. Perhaps the error originates from the data sources: `Vsurvey data to NameSplit` or `TT2870-LA Active` - are these queries or tables?

Comment: Vsurvey data to Namesplit is a query and TT2870-LA Active is a table. The Vsurvey data to Namesplit runs fine by itself.

Comment: @JHegde Are any of the target fields referenced in calculated fields?

Comment: I checked again and no the target fields are not referenced in the calculated fields.

Comment: @JHegde I have updated my answer above - I'm running out of ideas of how to help you debug this query.